# iPhone UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend ineffective

Tags: iphone, exit, multitasking

UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend does not force my app to exit. I have cleaned the target, removed the app, rebuilt, and reinstalled many times.

I really need my app to exit.

Answer (score 4):

Did you link against SDK 4? This key is only effective in this case.

Comment: For release and debug, my base SDK is iPhone Device 4.0.

My iPhone OS Deployment Target is iPhone OS 3.1.3.

Did I overlook a setting?

Comment: You have to deploy for 4.0 as well.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your application is still active ?

You will always see your application when double tapping the home button : **this is a list of the recently used apps, not a list of currently running apps**

Put a breakpoint in the applicationWillTerminate: method of your app delegate, if it stops in this method it means your is killed.

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when people type "set it to true in the plist file" what they really mean is:

1. Add "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend" as a key in the info.plist file
2. right-click on UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend and set "type" to boolean
3. click the checkbox that then appears

TRUE or YES in a string format does NOT work in the info.plist file.

BOOLEAN is the only flag that enables it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it helps you

in info.plist, add "Application does not run in background" = "YES".

thats it.now you open second time same application.It open with start page.

Thanks