# Quitting the iphone application properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I make sure the application quits properly when I hit the home button? When I hit the home button and open the app again, it starts off from where I left it and it has all the values (I'm making a calculator application). how do I make sure it starts from the beginning and not from where I left it. my app uses pickers and textfields. I added the following code and it's not helping!

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{   self.stage_picker = nil;
    self.grade_picker = nil;
    self.Pos_lymppicker = nil;
    self.Ex_lymphpicker = nil;
    self.text1 = nil;
    self.text2 = nil;
    self.text3 = nil;
    self.text4 = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

Comment: See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594963/iphone-uiapplicationexitsonsuspend-ineffective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the boolean key UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend or Application does not run in background
to your info.plist and set the value to yes

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

try this one

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the previous values while you start your app or when you close your app.

It is up to you. You can choose either of them.

So better to clear out all data on `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method or `applicationWillTerminate` method.

Now when you tap home button app goes in background, So if you want it to start freshly even when it is being started after being in background then you can clear out all data in `applicationDidnterBackground` method of application delegate.

Hope this helps you

Comment: thanks i managed to do this by adding 'applicatin does not run in background' in the .plist and set it value to YES. but out of curiosity. if i were to use the above method. what is the code that i should put into clear it all out ? is it the same one i typed in the viewdidunload ? I'm a beginner to iphone dev. thank you !

Comment: @cyberbemon: Also I would suggest you to look at Pierre answer. An excellent answer from him.